# Make a prototype board using ARM core

Tags: pcb, arm, prototyping

I'm a newbie here. I'm currently planning to make my own prototype board using an ARM chip. So I'll have to get the chip (which I have chosen to be SAM3S4A), and get some other components to support the chip e.g. regulator, caps, resistors, etc. But I am not sure what the components are, for me to get the chip working.
Maybe you can imagine this as a development board like arduino, it has its own core, but it needs supporting components to work. I'd like to make a board like this.

Any one here have ever done something like this? Developing a board out of the core and other components?

I would be really helped if anyone could share.

Comment: This is a pretty ambitious project for a newbie. Everything the part needs is in the datasheet (supply rails, oscillator, etc). Taking that information, understanding it, and implementing a working solution takes a combination of knowledge and experience, and I guarantee you won't get it right the first time.

Comment: Sure, do it all the time.  Things will be easiest if you can use an internal oscillator, a USB-serial cable, UART bootloader or external SWD or JTAG programmer (depending on ARM varient) and start out just trying to achieve serial message communication and blink a few led's.  Except for very obscure DIP devices, the 48-pin package devices are typically the easiest to work with by hand - you just have to get the footprint right, use flux, and solder by surface tension, rather than by trying to only touch one pin at a time.  Remember to get all the power/ground pairs and bypass caps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys!

@ChrisStratton I've chosen all the supporting components (regulators, clock circuit, JTAG, caps, etc) to get the chip working. I have bought the components and will be working on them soon on perfboard for testing, before i move on to printing a PCB. I'm going to use atmel studio via JTAG (I haven't considered USB). 

Is there anything I should tap on before I can code onto the chip (using C) just like coding onto arduino and other dev boards?

Comment: Not really sure what you plan to accomplish on perfboard, since the processor itself won't be compatible with that unless you buy an adapter.  And if you are planning to make a board (especially yourself), you may want to use almost all surface mount parts, since they are faster to assemble and it means fewer holes to drill.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes i'm using an adapter from 48pin QFP to DIP. The circuit I'm implementing on the perfboard is just to test whether my circuit works or not. If it's working I'm going to get everything SMD, and solder them to a PCB I will have designed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manufacturers usually want to make it easy to use their chips - as such there is often a reference design in the documentation that will show you how to get it up and running.

Taking a quick look at the [documentation](http://www.atmel.com/devices/sam3s4a.aspx?tab=documents) page for your chip shows that Atmel has provided a [Schematic Checklist](http://www.atmel.com/Images/11061.pdf). This will give you tips on how to hook up the power, reset, clock and other support circuitry.

You'll also need to consider how you will load software - does the chip have a preprogrammed bootloader (USB or serial say) or do you need a hardware programmer (JTAG etc).

If you're new to this, you might find that it's easier to get started with something like an 8-bit AVR. They can run off 5V from USB so you may not need a regulator (whereas most ARM micros run at 1.8-3.3V). They also have a simpler interrupt model, come with an internal oscillator and you can get them preprogrammed with a bootloader from [some suppliers](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10524).

Good luck with your project whatever you choose :)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply!

Yup I've considered using AVR actually, but because of some reasons I'll have to go for ARM straight. Of course I'd like to try AVR next time!

I've looked through the documents and from those and other dev boards' schematics I've chosen the supporting components. I will be working on them soon on perfboard for testing, before i move on to printing a PCB. I'm going to use atmel studio via JTAG (I haven't considered USB). 

Is there anything I should tap on before I can code onto the chip (using C) just like coding onto arduino and other dev boards?